# JSON AsyncTask refactoring to improve quality?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android. I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions. It's basically an `AsyncTask` to get a remote JSON array and put it into a native array.

Would be very grateful for suggestions.

```
package com.example.test2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String                  strCategoryJsonUrl      = "http://www.mydomain.com/categories.json";
getCategories                   myCategories;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myCategories            = new getCategories();
    myCategories.execute();
}//onCreate

private class getCategories extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... intMyGuessLevel) {
        String strJson  = "";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(strCategoryJsonUrl);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            strJson = readStream(con.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return strJson;
    } //doInBackground

    private String readStream(InputStream in) {
        BufferedReader  reader      = null;
        String          strContent  = "";

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                strContent  = strContent + line;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } //finally

        return strContent;
    } //readStream

    protected void onPostExecute(String strResult) {
        int i                   = 0;
        String strValue         = "";
        TextView txtDebug       = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdebug);
        String arrCategories[]  = new String[1];

        //parse JSON data
        try{
            JSONArray   jArray  = new JSONArray(strResult);
            //JSONObject  menu = jObject.getJSONObject("menu");
            arrCategories       =   new String[jArray.length()];

            for(i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(jArray.get(i).toString());

                strValue            = jObject.getString("name");

                //put value into array
                arrCategories[i]    = strValue;
            }

            //debug output the array
            txtDebug.setText(Arrays.toString(arrCategories));


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            txtDebug.append("Error in categories json file \n");
            txtDebug.append(String.valueOf(e));
        } // catch 


    } //onPostExecute
} //getJsonContent

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't open a resource in one place and close it in another. Keep the opening and closing of a resource localized to the same function (if you open it, you close it). This makes it easier to spot potential resource leaks.

For example, an `InputStream` is being opened in `doInBackground()`, but it is being closed in `readStream()`. Since `doInBackground()` opened the resource, it should be responsible for closing it.

---

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
```

You are not using anything specific to `HttpURLConnection`, so there is no reason to cast it. This works just fine:

```
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
```

---

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Don't ignore exceptions. Either let them continue up to the caller, or handle them appropriately. The `readStream()` function is a good example of where the exception should continue to the caller. Declare it as throwing `IOException` and remove the exception handling:

```
private String readStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    String content = "";
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        content += line;
    }
    return content;
}
```

---

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jArray.get(i).toString());
```

This can be simplified to this:

```
JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

---

Declare variables closer to there they are used. For example, in `onPostExecute()`: `i`, `strValue` and `arrCategories` are all declared at the top of the function, but are only ever used inside the `try` block.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String strResult) {
    TextView txtDebug = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtdebug);
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(strResult);
        String[] arrCategories = new String[jArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            arrCategories[i] = jObject.getString("name");
        }
        txtDebug.setText(Arrays.toString(arrCategories));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        txtDebug.append("Error in categories json file \n");
        txtDebug.append(String.valueOf(e));
    }
}
```

---

I would also like to see `onPostExecute()` broken down further. It is currently doing two things: parsing the JSON array and updating the UI. Move those into their own functions.

---

I am not a big fan of the comments in this code. I do not believe they add any value, and are only a distraction while reading.